# getting issue with collapsible panel using jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting issue with jquery toggle function.

Bellow i have attached link for demo...

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/WHmcY/1/)

**jquery code -**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsBTN').toggle(
        function () {
                $(".rhs_container").css({'display':'none'});
                $('.rhs').animate({width: "20"});
            },
        function () {
                $(".rhs_container").css({'display':'block'});
                $('.rhs').animate({width: "295"});
            }
    );
});
```

**Issue** - 
If we click on collaps button (in pink color as shown in above given link), toggle function works fine but button gets disappeared while animating width. It should be vissible with animation.

Can any one solve this?

Comment: F.Y.I. jQuery's [toggle() Event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function has [been removed](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfntogglehandler-handler-is-deprecated) as part of version 1.9.

Comment: for that i am using 1.8.2 version. or 
is there any other way to do the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, while jQuery animates over width, it makes `overflow:hidden` style. This one works, though:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZa99/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html 5 and css3 then follwoings would be better approach :

```
<script>
    $('.collapsBTN').click(function () { 

       $('.rhs_container).toggleClass('change-size');
   });

</script>

<style>
  .rhs{
       -webkit-transition: width 1.5s linear ;
       -moz-transition: width 1.5s linear ;
       transition: width 1.5s linear ;
   }

   .change-size {
       width: 20px;

   } 

  .change-size  .rhs_container{
       display:none;
   }
```

otherwise please check simple solution with jquery [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/WHmcY/34/embedded/result/)